# How do I make an input a number value

Tags: python, input

I just started coding today and I'm trying to write a simple program to add vectors. So far I have

```
VectorAx= input("What is the x component of Vector A?")
VectorAy= input("What is the y component of Vector A?")
VectorBx= input("What is the x component of Vector B?")
VectorBy= input("What is the y component of Vector B?")


VectorC= "[%s,%s]" % (VectorAx + VectorBx, VectorAy+VectorBy)
print (VectorC)
```

When I run the script everything works but the inputs aren't treated like numbers.
For example, if `VectorAx=1`, `VectorAy=6`, `VectorBx=3` and `VectorBy=2`, `VectorC` should be `[4,8]`, but instead it is displayed as `[13,62]`.

Answer (score 2):

`input` always returns a string object.  If you want the inputs to be numbers, you need to convert them into numbers with either [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float):

```
VectorAx= int(input("What is the x component of Vector A?"))
VectorAy= int(input("What is the y component of Vector A?"))
VectorBx= int(input("What is the x component of Vector B?"))
VectorBy= int(input("What is the y component of Vector B?"))
```

Demo:

```
>>> inp1 = int(input(":"))
:1
>>> inp2 = int(input(":"))
:2
>>> inp1 + inp2
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast your vectors to floats (if you plan on having decimals) or ints (if they will always be simple integers) then add.

Right now they are being taken in as strings.

Thus `"1"+"3" == "13"`

Whereas `int("1") + int("3") == 4`

Therefore:

```
VectorAx= int(input("What is the x component of Vector A?"))
VectorAy= int(input("What is the y component of Vector A?"))
VectorBx= int(input("What is the x component of Vector B?"))
VectorBy= int(input("What is the y component of Vector B?"))


VectorC= "[%s,%s]" % (VectorAx + VectorBx, VectorAy+VectorBy)
```

or you can simply cast here:

```
VectorC= "[%s,%s]" % (int(VectorAx) + int(VectorBx), int(VectorAy)+ int(VectorBy))
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the built-in [int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function.

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), this function will "convert a number or string x to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments are given."

This converts input passed to it to an integer.

So, the resulting code should be:

```
VectorAx = int(input("What is the x component of Vector A?"))
VectorAy = int(input("What is the y component of Vector A?"))
VectorBx = int(input("What is the x component of Vector B?"))
VectorBy = int(input("What is the y component of Vector B?"))
```

Comment: Yikes! Don't use `eval()` on user input! If anything, use `ast.literal_eval()` if necessary, but not for simple numbers.

Comment: Correct, my link however went to the `int` built-in function.

Comment: Correct, but you're looking at `int` (the type) not `int` (the function) which is a built-in function according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int.

Comment: To summarize. `int()` is just an invocation of `int` because both `functions` and `types/classes` are `callable` in Python. The documentation indeed mentions `int` as a built-in function. However the interpreter shows something else. `>>> type(int)` gives
`<type 'type'>` but `type(sorted)` gives `<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>`. There seems to be some inconsistency in the documentation.